# Linux kernel module mmap function not working correctly

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I am working on writing a kernel driver for pcie and for this purpose i need to map a buffer of size 4KB from user space to kernel space. Firstly a buffer is allocated at the kernel module initialization using kzalloc() and initialized to 0xff. The pointer of this buffer is then used in the mmap implementation from kernel side. The issue is that after mmap is called from the user space application the buffer is written to a csv file to check if mapping has been done correctly however the file shows certain regions with correct values (0xffffffff) and certain others with garbage values randomly a small portion of this is shown below:

00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
ffffffff
ffffffff
ffffffff
ffffffff
ffffffff
ffffffff
ffffffff
ffffffff
ffffffff
ffffffff
ffffffff
ffffffff
ffffffff
ffffffff
ffffffff
ffffffff
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
ffffffff
ffffffff
ffffffff
ffffffff
ffffffff
ffffffff
ffffffff
006bafdf
00000008
006c9fdf
00000008
00000000
00000000
006c1fdf

Whereas as per my understanding after the mapping all locations should have been printed as 0xffffffff. This is causing issue because I need to fill this buffer with data from the user application and give signal to the driver module so that it can transfer the data over pcie using writel() function. The kernel side code for the mapping is shown below:

```c
static int driver_mmap5(struct file *file, struct vm_area_struct *vma)
{
    int ret;
    vma->vm_flags  |= VM_LOCKED|VM_SHARED; 
    vma->vm_page_prot = pgprot_noncached(vma->vm_page_prot);
    ret = remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start,
          virt_to_phys(TEST5) >> PAGE_SHIFT,
          vma->vm_end-vma->vm_start, vma->vm_page_prot);
   if(ret != 0)
   printk("MMAP Failed \n");

   SetPageReserved(virt_to_page(TEST5));

   #ifdef DEBUG
    printk("MMAP Succeeded \n");
   #endif

   return 0;
}
```

where the TEST5 is pointer to the buffer to be mapped allocated as below:

```c
 long *TEST5;
 TEST5 = kzalloc(PB_BUFF_SIZE,__GFP_COLD|GFP_DMA);
 memset(TEST5,0xff,PB_BUFF_SIZE)
```

In the user space application another buffer is allocated and mapped as shown below:

```c
unsigned long* msg5;
msg5=(unsigned long*)malloc(PB_BUFF_SIZE);
```

and mmap is called:

```c
 msg5 = mmap(NULL, PB_BUFF_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED , fd, 0);
```

It appears that there is some problem with the mapping as some portions are mapped and some are not, hence the incorrect values. Kindly suggest the causes and solution to this issue.

Regards,

Edit: Adding the related code for both driver and application side below

**Driver Side code for buffer mapping**:

```c
long *TEST5;
#define PB_BUFF_SIZE 8192

static int driver_mmap5(struct file *file, struct vm_area_struct *vma)

{
  int ret;
    vma->vm_flags  |= VM_LOCKED|VM_SHARED; 
    vma->vm_page_prot = pgprot_noncached(vma->vm_page_prot);
                ret = remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start,
                      virt_to_phys(TEST5) >> PAGE_SHIFT,
                      vma->vm_end-vma->vm_start, vma->vm_page_prot);
  if(ret != 0)
   printk("MMAP Failed \n");

  SetPageReserved(virt_to_page(TEST5));

 #ifdef DEBUG
   printk("MMAP Succeeded \n");
 #endif

 return 0;

}

struct file_operations proc_fops5 = 
   {
     //.read  = read_proc,
     .write = write_proc5, 
     .mmap  = driver_mmap5,
   }; 


static void create_new_proc_entries(void) 
   {


    proc_create ("PCI_PICOZED_Param5",0,NULL, &proc_fops5);

    printk(KERN_DEBUG "Proc entries created successfully\n"); 

   } 

  static void Delete_proc_entries(void) 
   {

    remove_proc_entry ("PCI_PICOZED_Param5", NULL);

    printk(KERN_DEBUG "Proc entries removed successfully\n");
   } 

static int __init pci_skel_init(void)
  {

   TEST5 = kzalloc(PB_BUFF_SIZE,__GFP_COLD|GFP_DMA);
   memset(TEST5,0xff,PB_BUFF_SIZE);//test with mem
   printk("memset array ok\n");

   //adding print of few buffer values
   int i=0;
   for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    printk("alloc TEST5[%d]=%.8lx, add=%.lx\n",i,TEST5[i],TEST5+i);//should be 0xff

   return 1;   
  }



  static void __exit pci_skel_exit(void)
   {

    Delete_proc_entries();  
    kfree(TEST5);

   }


module_init(pci_skel_init);
module_exit(pci_skel_exit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Malik");
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(pci, PCI_ID_K);
```

**Application Side Code for buffer mapping and test**:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<sys/mman.h>
#include<string.h>


#define PB_BUFF_SIZE 8192
unsigned long *msg5 = NULL;

int main(int argc,char *argv[])//adding cmd line arguments to control the operating mode 
{
    int mode=0; //mode 1 for VDM, mode 2 for playback
    if(argc==2)
    {

        mode=atoi(argv[1]);
        printf("The operating mode is %d\n",mode);
    }
    else
    {
        mode=1;//default mode VDM
    }
    int fd,i;
    char str [10];
    //msg5=(unsigned long*)malloc(PB_BUFF_SIZE); //now commented as mmap returns allocated memory

    //buffer mapping
    if((fd=open("/proc/PCI_PICOZED_Param5", O_RDWR ))

<0)//open("/proc/PCI_PICOZED_Param", O_RDONLY )
        {
         printf("File not opened ");
        }

        printf("fd PCI_PICOZED_Param5 opened\n");

        msg5 = mmap(NULL, PB_BUFF_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED , fd, 0);
        if(msg5==MAP_FAILED)
        {
         printf("MAP failed and error is %s", strerror(errno));
         return 0;
        }
        close(fd);
       fd=open("Init_check_msg5.csv", O_CREAT | O_RDWR );
       for(i=0;i < PB_BUFF_SIZE/4 ;i++)
         {
            //fprintf(bf,"%.8lx\n",msg5[i]);
            sprintf(stri, "%.8lx\n",msg5[i]);
            write(fd,stri,20);
         }
       close(fd);
       return 0
    }
```

the values in the csv files are then checked which show the behavior as explained above.

Comment: There is something I cannot understand: why did you `malloc` `msg5` and then use `mmap` to overwrite it?

Comment: Are you checking `mmap` return value?

Comment: Yes i am checking the mmap return value, it returns successful. As per my understanding i need to allocate buffers on both kernel and application side and map them afterwards, is it not the case?

Comment: I also tried without using malloc on the driver side the result was similar to the original case as shown below:

dffbfeff
ceefefff
ffffffff
ffffffff
ee7a7ede
ffdffffe
fffeffff
fdffffff
fffffff7
ffffffff
ecfc1fbd
ebedb1fe
fbffffdf
ffffffff
5fff3fdf
fbffbfef
debdfffa
fffff7df
ffffffff
fffeefff
fe9edffe
7fffeeff
ffffffdf
fffbffff
f7ffffff
ffffffff
fddaffbf
fbfffbff
feffffff
ffffffff
f7fffffb
fffef7ed
f7e7fdf7
e4ffe6bf
edffffff
fffffbff
f77ddffd
dfffebff
fdffffff
fdffffff
ffffffff
fffffffb
ffff7ffb

Comment: You should post the driver code and the user space code. We don't know how fd  in user space is performed. How it is managed by driver.

Comment: We are using the same code for other buffers and they are working correctly, but in this single case the mapping/data is incorrect.

Comment: [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) is just around the corner....

Comment: @malik12 Please provide [minimal reproducible example](http://sscce.org/) for both the driver and user-space code. The problem can be in any line of code, so we need SSCCE to tell you where is it and why it is happening.

Comment: @malik12 Uncomfortable truth is, most likely nobody is gonna help you until you make your code really **minimal**. It must reproduce the problem you are facing, but it must be as little and essential as possible. It applies to both kernel and user-space part. You can read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for details.